# How to run cl.exe directly without running vcvars32.bat?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Every time when I have to run cl.exe to compile a cpp file, I have to run vcvars32.bat first. I searched for some similar questions, the solution is to write a .bat file, but I don't know how.

Comment: Open a appropriate Visual Studio Command Prompt from the start-menu shortcuts provided with your install. It sets up everything for you and you can run `cl.exe` to your hearts content.

Comment: You only have to run `vcvars32.bat` once, as long as you keep the Command Prompt open. Since you are not using the IDE you could aswell just use some other compiler like GCC, that wont require this kind of stuff.

Comment: You don't *have* to use vcvars32, you can also type the required PATH, INCLUDE and LIB environment variable assignments by hand.  Takes, oh, about fifty times longer and is a thousand times more likely to fail because of a typo.  Smart Thing to do here of course is to create a shortcut on your desktop so it just takes a single click.  Or to use the one you already have, usually called "Visual Studio Command Prompt".  Or to use the IDE of course.

Comment: thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @WhozCraig there are actually legitimate reasons to avoid calling `vcvars32.bat`. And the key reason is - it's VERY slow. If you're running `cl.exe` programmatically (through a batch file first running `vcvars32.bat`), bulk of time is spent in `vcvars32.bat`, for smaller files - more than compile time in `cl.exe` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to create a .bat file to start both of these processes it is going to look like this:

```
@echo off
start /wait vcvars32.bat
start /wait cl.exe
```

If you do not have these in the same folder as each other it would look like this:

```
@echo off
set path1= C:\testa
set path2= C:\testb
start /wait %path1%\vcvars32.bat
start /wait %path2%\cl.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3_compile.bat for example:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
cl sqlite3.c -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll
pause
```